# Is Android Device defaultly support mono

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop, xamarin

Is Android Device defaultly support mono ? or 
We need to install any thing on android device for supporting Mono(which the application developed by Xamarin).

Answer (score 4):

Xamarin's mobile/Mac solutions use a different approach compared to Microsoft .NET. The rules are,

1. You don't need to install a .NET/Mono runtime on Mac or iOS or Android devices before installing an app.
2. When you build the deployment packages of your app (Mac/iOS/Android), Mono compiler tool chain automatically merges your binaries with Mono binaries so the final packages are self contained (they contain every bits needed without dependencies on external components). This is required by Mac App Store, iOS App Store, and various Android app stores.

Note that because that Mono bits are embedded in each packages built, those packages are slightly larger than the ones created using Objective C or Java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it supports mono by default.

http://mono-project.com/Start